# How to make a button only clickable once

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I AM Microsoft Visual Studio
Basically I'm learning ASP and I'm trying to make an OnButtonClick postback.
But when ever I try to make it OnButtonClick = true; Return SendButton.visible = false

I need to make my 
SendButton_Click So that when someone clicks * send * the button becomes unclickable.

I've tried searching the web, Our I.T Guy said to google it but I just can't find what I need.

If someone can help.

I've attempted to use the following code, With no Succession.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var wasSubmitted = false;
function checkBeforeSubmit() {
    if (!wasSubmitted) {
        wasSubmitted = true;
        return wasSubmitted;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
<form onsubmit="return checkBeforeSubmit()" /> 
<asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="SendButton_Click OnClientClick="Disable" />
```

I want to make it so after the person has CLICKED: Send - They cannot click it multiple times there for sending the request multiple times.

Comment: just do `this.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')` in the button's onclick attribute see demo http://jsfiddle.net/bk26v/ can't get simpler

Comment: @Ahmad - what stops the button being disabled when there are validation failures and the form isn't submitted? How would the user be able to press the button after fixing the validation problems?

Comment: @JoeR I don't see anywhere the OP is doing form validation, seemed that he just wants the button clicked once, if not then I would agree with you yes

Comment: @Ahmad - true, I was assuming the button would be in a form that might, as least potentially, contain validation.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using WebForms have a look at [PostBack Ritalin](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PostBackRitalin/1.17.0) - it will do what you require very easily.

Or:

```
OnClientClick="if (!Page_ClientValidate()){ return false; } this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Please wait...';" 
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

This ensures the button isn't disabled when there are validation errors.

Comment: So Do I copy    function disableButton(myButton) {
     myButton.disabled = true;
     myButton.value = "submitting...."
     myButton.form.submit();
} Into the code behind file under Protected void SendButton_Click(Object sender, EVentArgs e)

Comment: I've removed the plain JavaScript version because of validation issues - we don't want to disable the button if the form has validation errors.